# PANDAS create column by iterating row by row checking values in 2nd dataframe until all values are true

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ItemNo' : ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005'], 
    'L'      : ['5', '65.0',  '445.0', '3200', '65000'], 
    'H'      : ['2', '15.5', '150.5', '1500', '54000'],
    'W'      : ['5', '85.0', '640.0', '1650', '45000'] 
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Rank'  : ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'Length': ['10', '100', '1000', '10000'],
    'Width' : ['10', '100', '1000', '10000'],
    'Height': ['10', '100', '1000', '10000'], 
    'Code'  : [ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'] 
})
```

So here I have two example dataframes. The first dataframe shows unique item numbers with given dimensions. df2 shows maximum allowable dimensions for given rank and code. Meaning all elements (length, width, height) must not exceed maximum given dimensions. I  would like to check the dimensions in df1 against df2 until all dimension criteria are True in order to retrieve it's 'rank' and 'code'. So, in essence, iterate down row by row of df2 until all the criteria is True.

Make a new df3 as follows:

```
ItemNo Rank Code
001    1     aa
002    2     bb
003    3     cc
004    4     dd
005    5     ee
```

Comment: `'Code'  : [ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'] ` this line for example is flawed, you should have 4 items not 5, same goes for others, you shuld have same length arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ItemNo' : ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006'], 
    'L'      : ['5', '65.0',  '445.0', '3200', '65000', '10'], 
    'H'      : ['2', '15.5', '150.5', '1500', '54000','1000'],
    'W'      : ['5', '85.0', '640.0', '1650', '45000', '10'] 
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Rank'  : ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'Length': ['10', '100', '1000', '10000', '100000'],
    'Width' : ['10', '100', '1000', '10000', '100000'],
    'Height': ['10', '100', '1000', '10000', '100000'], 
    'Code'  : [ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'] 
})

df_sort = pd.DataFrame({'W': np.searchsorted(df2['Width'].astype(float), df1['W'].astype(float)),
                   'H': np.searchsorted(df2['Height'].astype(float), df1['H'].astype(float)),
                   'L': np.searchsorted(df2['Length'].astype(float), df1['L'].astype(float))})

df1['Rank'] = df_sort.max(axis=1).map(df2['Rank'])
df1['Code'] = df1['Rank'].map(df2.set_index('Rank')['Code'])

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  ItemNo      L      H      W Rank Code
0    001      5      2      5    1   aa
1    002   65.0   15.5   85.0    2   bb
2    003  445.0  150.5  640.0    3   cc
3    004   3200   1500   1650    4   dd
4    005  65000  54000  45000    5   ee
5    006     10   1000     10    3   cc
```

The core to the code is the use of the [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) function. Which is used to find the index of the value of L in Length for example per the conditions listed in the documentations.  So, I use np.searchsorted for each of the three dimension then, I take the largest value using `max(axis=1)` and assign the rank and code based on that largest value using `map`.

Comment: I think your df_sort construction has reversed the 'L' column with width comparisons and the 'W' column with the length comparisons

Comment: I'm getting the correct output. I would really appreciate if you could give a short summation of what the code is doing for my understanding. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @bici-sancta Yep, labeled the columns incorrectly, didn't affect the logic.  Thanks fixed it.

Comment: @amitsingh Added a breif explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston i've got a bunch of these small problems need solving. i'm a newbie trying to do it on my own. Appreciate people like you willing to take the time to help

Comment: @amitsingh You're welcome.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a **numpy**

- changed sample data so that it's not just incrementing results
- get index of row in **df2** that matches required logic
- build **df3** using index in step 2

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ItemNo' : ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005'], 
    'L'      : ['5', '65.0',  '445.0', '5', '65000'], 
    'H'      : ['2', '15.5', '150.5', '5', '54000'],
    'W'      : ['5', '85.0', '640.0', '5', '45000'] 
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Rank'  : ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'Length': ['10', '100', '1000', '10000',100000],
    'Width' : ['10', '100', '1000', '10000',100000],
    'Height': ['10', '100', '1000', '10000',100000], 
    'Code'  : [ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'] 
})

# fix up datatypes for comparisons
df1.loc[:,["L","H","W"]] = df1.loc[:,["L","H","W"]].astype(float)
df2.loc[:,["Length","Height","Width"]] = df2.loc[:,["Length","Height","Width"]].astype(float)

# row by row comparison, argmax to get first True
idx = [np.argmax((df1.loc[r,["L","H","W"]].values 
                  < df2.loc[:,["Length","Height","Width"]].values).all(axis=1)) 
       for r in df1.index]

# finally the result
pd.concat([df1.ItemNo, df2.loc[idx,["Rank","Code"]].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

|  | ItemNo | Rank | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 001 | 1 | aa |
| 1 | 002 | 2 | bb |
| 2 | 003 | 3 | cc |
| 3 | 004 | 1 | aa |
| 4 | 005 | 5 | ee |